# JQuery $(window).load not working properly with Jinja template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

I'm trying to use JQuery to detect when the content of my pages are loaded and then resize the divs (navigation bar and content) on my page based on how much content there is. (For example, if there's a small amount of text, then the height of the divs are 800px, but when the navigation and content divs are different heights then set both equal to the largest height of the two.

```
        function resizePage(){
            var defaultSize = 600;
            var sidebarH = $("nav").height();
            var articleH = $("article").height();

            if((sidebarH < defaultSize) || (articleH < defaultSize)){
                $("nav").css({'height': defaultSize});
                $("article").css({'height': defaultSize});
            }
            else{
                if(sidebarH <= articleH){
                    $("nav").css({'height': articleH});
                }
                else{
                    $("article").css({'height': sidebarH});
                }
            }
        }

        $(window).load(function() {
            resizePage();
        });
```

When I modified the html code...now using Jinja templates...it seems like the template data is loaded in after the window is loaded thus it's not being resized properly. Is there a way JQuery can tell when template data has all been loaded? Or can I go about fixing this in a different way?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to change || to &&.

$(window).load versus $(document).ready didn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function resizePage() {
        var defaultSize = 600;
        var sidebarH = $("nav").height();
        var articleH = $("article").height();

        if((sidebarH < defaultSize) || (articleH < defaultSize)) {
            $("nav").css({'height': defaultSize});
            $("article").css({'height': defaultSize});
        }
        else{
            if(sidebarH <= articleH){
                $("nav").css({'height': articleH});
            }
            else{
                $("article").css({'height': sidebarH});
            }
        }
    }      

    resizePage(); // You are calling it here
});
```